# I need a help how to access the file in VM in java

Tags: java, virtual-machine

My requirement is to access the excel file and read the content from the file and need to process in Java. When i tried in my local machine using java (below code block) i did't see any issue. But when i tried the same code in **Citrix VM**, i was getting System could not find the path specified. I updated the path for the input file as per properties file in **VM** also. Any one's help is appreciated.

```
try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(
                "C:\\Users\\*****\\Desktop\\Input.xlsx"));
        // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
}
```

Comment: What did you do to confirm that the file is on the vm?

Comment: I do connect Citrix from my machine itself and copied the same file in VM..

Comment: I am not familiar with Citrix, but looking quickly at a thing or two on the web, it appears to have a unix-like file structure. In that case, it isn't going to have a "C:" drive, and it isn't going to use backslash as a folder separator. Make sure you are using a string that specifies the file in the right file system.

Comment: Is this a Citrix windows vm? If so, use explorer to view the directory and confirm that your file is there.

Comment: Hi Don, the below is the path  for that file                                                     FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(
     "\\HSYPWCTXFS001\\CTX_Home$\\***\\Desktop\\Input.xlsx"));

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. I don't think I can help.